# How do I query images from multiple tables in SQLite3

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a SQlite database of images with the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE crowd_labels (mid int, attribute text, label text, primary key (mid, attribute));

CREATE TABLE modules (
    mid int primary key,
    project_id int,
    src text
, mature_content, license);

CREATE TABLE scores (mid int,content_bicycle real, content_cat real, content_tree real, emotion_scary real, media_oilpaint real, content_bird real, content_dog real, emotion_gloomy real, media_3d_graphics real, media_pen_ink real, content_building real, content_flower real, emotion_happy real, media_comic real, media_vectorart real, content_cars real, content_people real, emotion_peaceful real, media_graphite real, media_watercolor real);
```

I can do the following queries separately, but I want to know how I can combine them into a single query:

```
sqlite3 mydatabase.sqlite <<EOF  > cat_pictures.htm
    select "<img src=""" || src || """ height=200>"
    from modules, crowd_labels where modules.mid = crowd_labels.mid
    and attribute = "content_cat"
    and label="positive"
    limit 100;
EOF

sqlite3 mydatabase.sqlite <<EOF  > watercolor_pictures.htm
    select "<img src=""" || src || """ height=200>"
    from modules, scores where modules.mid = scores.mid
    order by media_watercolor desc limit 0,100;
EOF
```

The first query will return an html file of 100 images of cats, by checking against the "crowd_labels" table and the second query will give me back an html file of 100 water color images by checking against the "scores" table.

But if I wanted to combine the two, that is, give me back the intersection of images that are both cats AND watercolor, how do I do this?

Sorry if this is a very simple question but I have 0 background experience in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join all three tables:

```
SELECT '<img src="' || src || '" height=200>'
FROM modules
JOIN crowd_labels USING (mid)
JOIN scores       USING (mid)
WHERE attribute = 'content_cat'
  AND label     = 'positive'
ORDER BY media_watercolor DESC
LIMIT 100;
```